# Magento 2 system configuration state multiselect dropdown

Tags: magento-2.2.5, system.xml, dynamic, state

First i have created country drop-down in back-end system configuration, using source model as

```
<source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
```

Next based on country selected, I need to populate states of that country in a multi-select field below country field.

Currently, there is option for loading state a single select drop-down. But I need it as multi-select attribute..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="new_section">
            <group id="general">
                 <field id="address_country_id" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Applicable Countries</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                    <frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>
                </field>
                <field id="address_region_id" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Applicable Region/State</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question what you have tried for single select dropdown?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

1.If you need multi-select field at the system.xml of all country list then add the filed just like below in your group.

```
  <field id="address_country_id" translate="label comment" type="multiselect" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Applicable Countries</label>
            <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
            <frontend_class>countries</frontend_class>
   </field>
```

2.please flush the Cache.

Comment: There are two fields country and state. I want the country as select field and based on country selected respected states for that country as multiselect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below to get the multiselect dropdown

Ship to Specific Countries
    Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country
    1

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery and ajax, fetch the id of the selected option in jquery and call a callback ajax function which redirects to its controller and update the second dependent dropdown using its ID in Success part

Answer (score 0):

**Add new field in UI form**

```
<field name="group">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">{Vendor}\{Module}\Model\Model\Source\Myvalues</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Your Label</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**Now create `Myvalues.php` to provide multiselect options at**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Model/Source/Myvalues.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Myvalues;

class Myvalues implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Test One')],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('Test Two')],
            ['value' => 3, 'label' => __('Test Three')],
        ];
    }
}
```